# Rubyで文字付きの連番配列を作るには

Tags: ruby

```
['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4']
```

このような配列を作りたいのですがどうやればいいのでしょうか。
普通の数字やアルファベットだけやるときみたいに`[*1..4]`のように['a'*1..4]という感じでできないのでしょうか。

Answer (score 3):

Arrayのコンストラクタにブロックを渡せるので、以下のように書くのが一番素直なような気がします。

```
Array.new(4) {|i| "a#{i + 1}" }
```

Answer (score 2):

`[*'a1'..'a4']` でできます。

Comment: `[*'a1'..'a10']`としてしまうとものすごいことになってしまいました。10位上は対応していないのでしょうか。

Comment: @fybjai 桁数を合わせる必要がありますので、`[*'a01'..'a10']` とします。

Comment: ゼロ埋めしていない配列を作りたいのですがこの方法では無理そうですね。
他に書き方はないでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

こんなのはどうでしょう？

```
(1..20).map{|i| "a#{i}"}
=> ["a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "a6", "a7", "a8", "a9", "a10", "a11", "a12", "a13", "a14", "a15", "a16", "a17", "a18", "a19", "a20"]
```

あとはこんなのとか

```
['a'].product([*1..20]).map(&:join)
=> ["a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "a6", "a7", "a8", "a9", "a10", "a11", "a12", "a13", "a14", "a15", "a16", "a17", "a18", "a19", "a20"]
```

おそらく`['a'*1..4]`のようなレベルで書くのは無理で、いくつかのメソッドを組み合わせる必要はあると思います。

Comment: あと別件ですが、疑問が解決したら「[回答の承認](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)」を行って質問を解決済みにしてくださいね。プロフィールを確認させてもらったところ、解決済みになっている質問がひとつもなかったので。ちなみに回答の承認をすると自分の信用度もアップします！

Answer (score 0):

`[]`メソッドに`Range`を渡すとプレフィックスがついた連番を返すクラスを実装すると良いのではないでしょうか

```
class PrefixedSequence
  def initialize(prefix)
    @prefix = prefix
  end

  def [](range)
    range.map {|x| "#{@prefix}#{x}"}
  end
end

a_seq = PrefixedSequence.new(?a)

a_seq[1..10]
```